# I cannot install ipython package on WSL with Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 11: "Package ipython is not available, but is referred to by another package."

Tags: 20.04, python3, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pip, ipython

I'm trying to install `ns-3` on my Windows 11 using Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL), but when running:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygraphviz python-kiwi python-pygoocanvas libgoocanvas-dev ipython
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ipython is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package python-pygraphviz
E: Unable to locate package python-kiwi
E: Unable to locate package python-pygoocanvas
E: Unable to locate package libgoocanvas-dev
E: Package 'ipython' has no installation candidate.
```

I've already tried all other instructions, but nothing helped. I tried `sudo apt install -y python3-pip`, `pip3 install ipython`, etc.
Please, someone help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: I enabled universe and multiverse also, still doesn't work.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1420626/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 0):

I exactly had the same error when installing ipython on WSL with Ubuntu. As suggested, an update of the package sources list solved the problem. Just execute

```
sudo apt update
```

and then try again.